# How do you find out if a site has mouse movement detection and/or recording installed?

Tags: python, web-scraping, mouseevent, mouselistener

I'm doing web scraping with Python on difficult sites such as Instagram, Facebook, and so on... Since it is likely that these sites do monitor your mouse movements in order to recognize scrapers vs real humans. What I do struggle find out it **how to find out if a site has one of these mouse tracking, detecting, and/or movement recording, installed?** And as browsers do state that even with their tracking option turned off it is still impossible to know how the scraped site would interpret this, **are there reliable options to turn mouse movement monitor services off?**

Comment: Are you sure the TOS allows scraping? You shouldn't be trying to get around their anti-scraping techniques if you shouldn't be doing it in the first place.

Comment: You could try searching all the JavaScript files that are loaded to see if any of them mention the mouse movement events. But they might be obfuscated, which will make this difficult.

Comment: According to the law, it is actually legal to scrape public data not just not copyrighted and private data (private accounts, etc) but the issue here is that they prefer real human users and hence would ban detected bots and so

Comment: I tried to look through the elements and source code but couldn't determine the common keywords that would be attached if mouse movement monitoring are used except for "mouse" I suppose..

Comment: There's no reason this should be easy. There's no obvious way to tell the difference between mouse events that are used for the application and mouse tracking being used for anti-scraping.